# How to detect the last line in awk before END

Tags: shell, awk, line

I am trying to add last line to the file which I am creating. How is it possible to detect the last line of a file in awk before `END` ? I need to do this because the variables don't work in the `END` block, 
so I am trying to avoid using `END`.

```
awk ' { do some things..; add a new last line into file;}'
```

before `END`, I don't want this:

```
awk 'END{print "something new" >> "newfile.txt"}'
```

Comment: Which variables in particular do you need that are not available in the END block?  Most of the variables (`NR`, `NF`, `FNR`, etc. )  have very reasonable values in the END block.

Comment: the variables i need are some local variables which play the main role in creating the file.. e.g.: 
``print $0 >> sprintf("%s/%s_%s.txt", user, mode, FILENAME)``
those ``user`` and ``mode`` are not available in ``END`` which are becoming the name of the file...

Comment: This question makes no sense. Awk doesn't have local variables, other than function parameters. If you calculate a file name and put it into `fname`, then `fname` will retain its value until either Awk terminates, or a new value is assigned into `fname`.

Comment: When you're processing any record of the input, assume that it **might** be the last one, and calculate the file name that will be required in that case, putting it into a variable called `fname`. If that record is the last one, then the `END` block will execute, and `fname` will be available then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use `getline` function to process the file. It returns `1` on sucess, `0` on end of file and `-1` on an error.

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 {

        ## Process first line.
        print FNR ": " $0;

        while ( getline == 1 ) {
            ## Process from second to last line.
            print FNR ": " $0;
        }

        ## Here all lines have been processed.
        print "After last line";
    }
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with this data:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

Output will be:

```
1: one                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2: two                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
3: three
4: four
5: five
After last line
```

Comment: great, this is what i want, i think. let me give a shot

Comment: @doniyor: Then don't accept the answer yet, because it could discourage other users to post different solutions. Do it when you are sure. Time is not a problem, isn't it?

Comment: Nicely done; unless there is a need to treat the first line special, you could rewrite the loop to use `do { ... } while (getline == 1)`, in which case you don't need the `print` statement preceding the loop.

Comment: This has been accepted but I do not really see the point as it can simply be done by: cat <file>; echo "line" >> <file> .. and adding things using awk can be simply done with what you "do not want". Using getline sounds like you want to use something else as you cannot pipe it till the process is done.

Comment: Fo pipe I mean that your awk might load all in RAM.... I have the same problem but I think I need to use a different approach. I cannot vote down this solution, but please vote it down!

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ENDFILE`, it executes before `END`:

```
$ awk 'END {print "end"} ENDFILE{print "last line"}'  /dev/null /dev/null
last line
last line
end
```

ENDFILE exists in latest version of GNU awk (>4.0 I think).

Answer (score 10):

Print the previous line.
  When current line is 2, print line 1,
  when current line is 3, print line 2.
  ....
  till the end

```
awk '{
    if (NR>1) {
        # process str
        print str;
    }
    str=$0;
}
END {
    # process whatever needed before printing the last line and then print the last line.
    print str;
}'
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cat file 
1
2
3
4
5
```

By reading same file twice ( Recommended )

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{last++;next}{print $0, ((last==FNR)?"I am Last":"")}' file file
1
2
3
4
5 I am Last
```

Using `getline`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{while((getline t < ARGV[1]) > 0)last++;close(ARGV[1])}{print $0, ((last==FNR)?"I am Last":"")}' file
1
2
3
4
5 I am Last
```

Comment: This is weird. It works for me on the Cygwin bash command line, if I use the exact input file you posted. But if I use a different input file, it does not. My file is comprised of the lines "x line x" where x does from 1 to 8.

Comment: @ysap thanks for reporting, I noticed it didn't work with even no of rows, modified now

Comment: Thanks. Trying it as you posted, it does not print the last line's contents (`8 line 8`). Just the message.

Comment: @ysap: please try : `seq 8 > testfile; awk 'BEGIN{while((getline t < ARGV[1]) > 0)last++;close(ARGV[1])}{print $0 ((last==FNR)?" I am Last":"")}' testfile`

Comment: Looks like it originates from a limitation of awk, where printing the whole input line is not working if it is followed by more characters. If you switch the order of the message and the $0, then it works:`print ((last==FNR) ? "I am Last: ":"") $0
`

Comment: This awk behavior is very annoying and I do not know why it happens.

Comment: You need to change the `print $0 (() ? : )` line as I suggested in order to actually see the line.

Comment: @ysap not really needed, which version of awk are you using ?, you may use comma, like `print $0 , (() ? : )` if you want other separator incase if you set something like `-v OFS='|'`, I added comma in above post too, for better reading, actually there is no need if you want space as separator

Comment: `GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)`. I did not change the default `OFS`. Adding a comma does not work for me either.

Comment: did you try with comma ? `awk 'FNR==NR{last++;next}{print $0, ((last==FNR)?"I am Last":"")}' file file`

Comment: @ysap please note with pipe it will not work in case if you have `yourcommand | awk '{ } '`, unfortunately I don't have cygwin to test, did you forget to give input file twice by any chance ?

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding here - what I referred to as "not working" was the fact that the last line from the input file is not printed before the "I am Last" message. Otherwise, your script detects the last line correctly, and prints the message.

Comment: Oh okay, for that you may use `RS` variable or `"\n"`  would look like this  `print $0  RS (() ? : )`

Comment: OK, this is how it should be: `print $0 ((last==FNR) ? "\nI am Last" : "")` (of course, it prints the message in the next line, but you get to see the last input line).

Comment: @ysap since OP hasn't specified how o/p should look like, so I have not added newline char

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of lines in a file using `"wc -l" | getline filesize` in the begin block and use `NR == filesize` to test the last line in the script body.

Comment: thanks, but my case is this: 
i have a huge file which i should sort into multiple small files. those multiple small files which i am creating at the moment should be in rtf format. so, i dont know in advance the number of lines of the new file.. :(

Comment: why don't you convert them to rtf after the awk?

Comment: because the files i am creating and distributing are in different directories. after awk i have to look for the created files then, it is more job.

Comment: I would go for 'END { system"(convert_to_rtf "FILENAME); }' or doing similar with an array of names. I think this is cleaner.

Comment: well, this is also good. but the only thing i am trying to achieve is that the file should be in landscape format, this is why the rtf code is there... ``\landscape``

Comment: **Caveat**: As written, the `wc`-based pipeline command will only work with `stdin` input due to lack of explicit input - which is a catch-22: the command will exhaust the stdin input, causing subsequent blocks in the awk program to have no input left. To use this approach, (a) make sure that an actual filename was specified and (b) refer to it explicitly: `"wc -l < \""ARGV[1]"\"" | getline lineCount; lineCount+=0` (The `lineCount+=0` part is for platforms such as OSX where `wc -l` outputs leading whitespace; it ensures that awk treats `lineCount` as a number.)

Comment: @mklement0 - thanks for the updated version. This solution enabled me to effectively use the `rewind() ` function with an unspecified (i.e., data file dependent) number of repetitions. So, instead of awkwardly using `getline`, I test for the EOF as proposed here.

Answer (score -1):

I know the answer was accepted, but it is simply wrong.

Because you do want to use awk as a parser and not as a code.

Awk should be used within some unix pipes and it should not be used within any logic.

I had the same problem and I solved it within awk like this:

nlines=`wc -l <file>`

cat  | awk -v nl=${nlines} '{if (nl != NR) {print $0,",","\";} else {print;}}' >>  ${someout}

There is an important point here: pipes, flush, and RAM.

If you make awk to spit out its output you can pipe it to the next processor.

If you use getline, and in particular within a loop, you might not see the end.

getline should be used only for a line and an eventual dependency on the next line.

I love awk, but we cannot do everything with it!

EDITED:

For whom down-voted the answer, I just want to present this script:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# Generate random strings
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 100000 > x.r.100000
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1000000 > x.r.1000000
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 5000000 > x.r.5000000
#
# To save you time in case
#cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 10000000 > x.r.10000000
#
# Generate awk files
cat <<"EOF" > awkGetline.sh
#! /bin/sh
#
awk '
    FNR == 1 {

        ## Process first line.
        print FNR ": " $0;

        while ( getline == 1 ) {
            ## Process from second to last line.
            print FNR ": " $0;
        }
    }
' x.r
#
EOF
#
chmod +x awkGetline.sh
#
cat <<"EOF" > awkPlain.sh
#! /bin/sh
#
awk '
    {print FNR ": " $0;}
' x.r
#
EOF
#
# x.r.100000
#
chmod +x awkPlain.sh
#
# Execute awkGetline.sh 10 times on x.r.100000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.100000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkGetline.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Getln", sum;}' | grep SUM
#

#
# Execute awkPlain.sh 10 times on x.r.100000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.100000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkPlain.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Plain", sum;}' | grep SUM
#

#
# x.r.1000000
#
chmod +x awkPlain.sh
#
# Execute awkGetline.sh 10 times on x.r.1000000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.1000000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkGetline.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Getln", sum;}' | grep SUM
#

#
# Execute awkPlain.sh 10 times on x.r.1000000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.1000000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkPlain.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Plain", sum;}' | grep SUM
#


#
# x.r.5000000
#
chmod +x awkPlain.sh
#
# Execute awkGetline.sh 10 times on x.r.5000000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.5000000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkGetline.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Getln", sum;}' | grep SUM
#

#
# Execute awkPlain.sh 10 times on x.r.5000000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.5000000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkPlain.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Plain", sum;}' | grep SUM
#

exit;
# To save you time in case

#
# x.r.10000000
#
chmod +x awkPlain.sh
#
# Execute awkGetline.sh 10 times on x.r.10000000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.10000000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkGetline.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Getln", sum;}' | grep SUM
#

#
# Execute awkPlain.sh 10 times on x.r.10000000
rm -f x.t
cp x.r.10000000 x.r
for runInstance in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
  do
  /usr/bin/time -p -a -o x.t ./awkPlain.sh > x.1.out;
done;
#
cat x.t | grep real | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0.0} {sum=sum+$2; print $2, sum/10;} END {print "SUM Plain", sum;}' | grep SUM
#
```

And of course the first results:

```
tmp]$ ./awkRun.sh 
SUM Getln 0.78
SUM Plain 0.71
SUM Getln 7.2
SUM Plain 6.49
SUM Getln 35.91
SUM Plain 32.92
```

Where you save about 10% of the time just because of the getline.

Consider this within more complex logic and you might get even a worst picture. In this plain version, memory consideration are not accounted.
And seems they do not play a role for this simple version. But memory might also play a role if you get into more complex logic ...

Of course try it on your machine.

This is why I was suggesting to consider other options, in general.

Comment: A note: Using pipes I could handle large data, a bit of time indeed, but I could get results. Using awk too. In commodity machines. Please do not make awk a monster, do not use getline.

Comment: I agree with using `wc` instead `getline`, but, I have two minor quibbles. First, use `nlines=$(wc -l < filename)` (notice the redirection of stdin) so that nlines doesn't look like: `80 filename`. Second, I don't think your benchmark's valid. In `x.r` you should add in the time it takes to do the `wc` and the test for `FNR==nlines`. My guess is that the getline solution is actually faster because you are only parsing `filename` once.