# How to "roll back" a getline call?

Tags: awk, getline, gawk

If I use `getline` in my awk script, it reads the next line from the stream and updates the $0 and NR variables (as it should). Is there a way to un-`getline`?

For example, I want to use `getline` to determine the EOF and then take an action on that. But if the condition is false (i.e., not EOF), then the script should continue normally.

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

{
    print $0;

    if (getline == 0)
    {
        print "EOF";
    } else {
        ungetline;
    }
}
```

Without the `ungetline`, the above script will only print every other input line.

One can wrap the whole script body with a `while()` construct, but for this single use, it is just cleaner to undo the operation.

Comment: what you have asked is not possible, probably what you can do is read it in array, and iterate using loop in END block, like `awk '{ arr[FNR]=$0;} END{ for(i=1; i in arr; i++){  nf=split(arr[i], tmparr); print "Line : "i, "No of Fields ( NF )", nf;   } }' infile`, array `tmparr` will have field data of each row, which you can again loop it

Comment: Thanks. Doing it this way is actually a creative idea. A possible caveat, though, is that it converts my program to a regular "C"-like program, only written in awk syntax, as I need to now take care of iterating through the file. Might as well use C for that (althogh I do take advantage on awk's pattern matching and associative arrays.

Comment: IIUC, you are looking for looking for something like in C, `fetll, fseek`,if so you may [read](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/PEwCY1o3tA0)

Comment: there is probably a "no getline" solution to your problem.

Comment: @karakfa - thanks. Yes, there is, and I am actually using it in my script, as I think it is more elegant than `getline`. See the correction comment to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142006/274579

Comment: @3161993 - I looked at the post, and my understanding is that they concluded that there is *no way* to implement `ftell`, `fseek`.

Comment: This is an [XY Question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwju-pPr_IvXAhWI3YMKHbj8D5wQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxyproblem.info%2F&usg=AOvVaw0RGK_DaXai8CXEqvdNCf1g). If you tell us what you want to do rather than how you want to do it, complete with a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output, then we can help you. As written you're likely to get some wacky hack of a piece of code trying to do what you are asking to do when there's a simple, elegant alternative.

Comment: @EdMorton - no, it is not. Per your linked-to page, an XY Question is "asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem". I was not interested in asking about my problem. It is *my* problem. Nor did I ask about my attempted solution. I merely gave a usage example as a motivation. My question was simple - is there a way to achieve this and that behavior. Specifically - **Is there a way to un-`getline`**?

Comment: That's like asking "Is there a way to undig a hole". The answer is "fill it in again with the pile of dirt you created" but that still leaves us wondering why you thought you should dig a hole in the first place and if we knew THAT then we could help you to solve your problem rather than telling you how to implement the solution you think you need. Hence, it's an XY Problem. And yes, of course there's a way to un-getline (this is software so anything's possible) but it will be the wrong solution to whatever problem you really have.

Comment: @EdMorton - I guess we have to disagree. I already have a solution to my problem, not employing `getline`. I wanted to know exactly what I asked for in the question. In C there is that `ungetc()` function that can be used in a  similar manner. I thought maybe we can have similar functionality for `getline`.

Comment: And maybe you can but without concise, testable sample input and expected output we'd just be guessing at what you want. @karakfa guessed and apparently got it wrong. idk if others will follow...

Comment: @EdMorton - added a sample script. You insist on me describing my actual problem. I don't want to describe my actual problem. Let's say I don't have a problem, and am just curious about having `ungetline`. @karakfa, effectively, answered a question I did not ask...

Comment: Posting your script is a good start to asking a question but we also need the rest of the [mcve] which would include concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask] if that's not clear. One example of why it matters is there can be a solution for input that's stored in a file that would not work for input coming from a pipe.

Comment: @EdMorton - again, we will continue to disagree. Anyone **remotely** capable of answering *this* question, can easily employ that script on a sample 4-line input and see the *actual* result. I think that my description I added below the script tells the whole story. I am done arguing on this, but thank you for your input.

Comment: I feel like I might be **remotely** capable of answering most awk questions and the script you posted would spin off into an infinite loop printing EOF repeatedly given any obvious implementation of "ungetline" - I doubt if that's what you want it to do so it doesn't tell us what you do want it to do. You're wrong in saying "Without the ungetline, the above script will only print every other input line." I'm done too though so - good luck with whatever it is you are trying to do and if you do need help in future just remember to include a [mcve] so we have something to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that's the problem you're solving but for example, to print a line before the last line of the input you can follow "delaying printing" method.  Here it's just printing the line but any processing can be similarly added.

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'NR>1 {print line} 
                    {line=$0} 
               END  {print "and finally..."; print line}'

1
2
3
4
and finally...
5
```

based on your updated posting, perhaps your use case is just the simulate the `END` block.

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{print $1*$1} 
           END {print "EOF"}'

1
4
9
16
25
EOF
```

either you do something before the last line or after the last time; both cases are covered in these scripts.  You can have a combination of these two as well.  I'm still not sure about your use case...

Comment: Thanks. This is a solution to a very specific problem, I think. In my actual case, I am processing a file with multiple passes (so, initially, using `getline` and `rewind()`, but then I changed to the `wc -l` method), but the number (and nature) of the passes is data dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My usecase is not similar to the sample script. I think I described it in the other question. If you insist, then I need to be able to process stuff before and after the `getline` call, and definitely before reaching the `END` block.